# How can I get values from dictionary for particular key using python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, input, output

In this code, I wanted to identify a member with his ID. If the ID exist in the dictionary, I would like to print the fullname of this member

```
iin = input('Enter your ID :')
 dict = {'id' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
        'Firstname' : ['Mark', 'Jamal', 'Van'],
        'Lastname' : ['Roch', 'borh', 'nilsa']}
 for d in dict:
    if inn in d:
       print('Hello,', dict[inn])
    else :
       print('Sorry, you are not a member')
```

The desired result

```
Enter your ID : aa
Hello, Mark Roch
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Get the index of your ID from the first dictionary element (list) and use it to access the other lists: `dict["Firstname"][index]`

Comment: But your code won't work as `d` only gets you the dictionary keys "id", "Firstname", etc. You want to test ìn dict[d]` to get to the lists.

Comment: Exactly that, but i'm stuck can you give me the good syntax! thanks

Comment: @K.ossama: I have added few explainations with my answer. Hope those may help, because there are basic programming issues with your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the below code with comments inline.

```
iin = input('Enter your ID :')
d = {'id' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
        'Firstname' : ['Mark', 'Jamal', 'Van'],
        'Lastname' : ['Roch', 'borh', 'nilsa']}
#Get list of IDs    
id_list = d['id']

#Check input in list
if iin in id_list:
    #Get index of input from ID list
    index = id_list.index(iin)
    #Get rest of info
    fname = d['Firstname'][index]
    lname = d['Lastname'][index]
    msg = "Hello, " + fname + " " + lname
    print msg
else:
    print 'Sorry, you are not a member'
```

Output :

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python b.py
Enter your ID :"aa"
Hello, Mark Roch

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python b.py
Enter your ID :"asd"
Sorry, you are not a member

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Comment: thank you @Dinesh Pundkar! the code works now perfectly

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to loop over all the items in the dictionary; it would be silly to look for an id in the `Firstname` and `Lastname` fields.  (And this could produce incorrect results if the entered id happens to be a substring of someone's name.)

What you want is to check if the given id is present in the id list, and if so, use that list position to print the corresponding first and last names:

```
if iin in dict['id']:
   index = dict['id'].index(iin)
   print('Hello, %s %s' % (dict['Firstname'][index], dict['Lastname'][index]))
else :
   print('Sorry, you are not a member')
```

Some suggestions:

It might be easier if you arranged your data as a list of dicts each containing a single member, like so:

```
members = [
    {'id': 'aa', 'Firstname': 'Mark',  'Lastname': 'Roch'},
    {'id': 'bb', 'Firstname': 'Jamal', 'Lastname': 'borh'},
    {'id': 'cc', 'Firstname': 'Van',   'Lastname': 'nilsa'},
]
```

Don't name your dictionary `dict`, as that conflicts with a built-in function name.

Comment: `dict` is a class name. `dict(...)` is actually calling the initializer and constructor.

Comment: Thank you @John Gorden for the help! your code is clear

Answer (score 0):

The working version of the code should be:

```
my_dict = {'id' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
           'Firstname' : ['Mark', 'Jamal', 'Van'],
               'Lastname' : ['Roch', 'borh', 'nilsa']}
iin = input('Enter your ID :')
# Enter your ID :"bb"
try:
    my_id = my_dict['id'].index(iin)
    print my_dict['Firstname'][my_id], ', ', my_dict['Lastname'][my_id]
except ValueError:
    print 'Sorry, you are not a member'    
# Jamal ,  borh
```

**Exlaination/Issues with your code:**

1. `for d in dict` means `for d in dict.keys()` which will return `['id', 'FirstName', 'LastName'`. In order to iterate over id, you should be doing `for d in dict['id']`. In fact, iterating over the list itself is not required. To get `index` of element in ;list, you may simply use `list.index(element)` function
2. `dict` is the `built-in` class in `python`. You should  never use the keywords
3. You dictionary structure is itself not correct. By definition, `dict means collections of objects` and object means similar entities. In this case, Person. Since id is supposed by unique, in am making nested dict with key as `id` (you may also use list of dict):

   ```
   {'aa': {'Firstname' : 'Mark',
           'Lastname' : 'Roch'},
    'bb': {'Firstname' : 'Jamal',
           'Lastname' : 'borh'},
    'cc': {'Firstname' : 'Van',
           'Lastname' : 'nilsa'},
   }
   ```

Comment: You should catch exceptions if the input id does not exist.

Comment: @TerrenceBrannon: Yes, I should have done that. Thanks. Updated the answer

Comment: `dict` is a builtin class name, not a keyword. Overwriting it is a bad idea regardless, as you said.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Yes it is a class. Updated it

Comment: Does anyone have any idea, why my answer is down voted? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Building on [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

```
iin = input('Enter your ID :')
dict = {'id' : ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
        'Firstname' : ['Mark', 'Jamal', 'Van'],
        'Lastname' : ['Roch', 'borh', 'nilsa']}
try:
    i = dict['id'].index(iin)
    print('Hello {0} {1}'.format(dict['Firstname'][i], dict['Lastname'][i])
except ValueError:
    print('Sorry, you are not a member')
```

**NOTE**: you cannot name a dictionary `dict` because it conflicts with a keyword.

Comment: You can name a dictionary `dict`, but it will shadow the name of the class. `dict` is not a keyword.